# extends Component<Props> vs extends React.Component

Tags: react-native

What's the difference between

```
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props>
```

And

```
export default class App extends React.Component
```

Both ways of extending seem to work without any errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<Props>` part is just [Flow](https://flow.org/en/) feature for type checking. It will be ignored if you haven't integrated Flow.
`Component` and `React.Component` is the same class from `react` package, a difference only in importing:

```
import React from 'react';
export default class App extends React.Component

import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class App extends Component
```